# About extracting data from a website (Python)

Tags: python

I made a program to extract information from a website. It works like below:

```
for row in table.findAll('td'):
    topas = row.find('p')
    pastoo = row.find('ul')
    if topas:
        continue
    elif pastoo:
        continue
    else:
        input = row.get_text()
        input.strip()
        file.write(input)
        file.write("~") #adding separator
```

It works perfectly when the .html file is well-formated,  like this:

```
<table class="responsiveTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Country:</td><td>Belgium</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Year:</td><td>various years</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, in some .html files, things are quite messy which look like this:

```
<table class="responsiveTable">
<tbody><tr><td>Country:</td><td>Indonesia</td></tr>
**<tr><td>Year:</td><td>2017 (Jan 27th)             
</td></tr>**
</tbody></table>
```

As you can see, the 4th row of the code made an unnecessary line break. I tried to use .strip() to remove it but it didn't work. Is there any strong function which can remove the line break?? Thank you!!

Comment: Use [Beatifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) if you want to do webscraping. This will beat any handmade solution

Comment: I'd consider using a proper web scraping module like Beautiful Soup.

Comment: @TomWyllie And `lxml`...